# re-size JTable when useing Default table model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, preferredsize

I have a JTable built using DefaultModel which is displayed in JPane but I would like to re-size the table to make it bigger. Could any one please explain how I could do that? I have tried the following code:

```
TableColumnModel colsize = t1.getColumnModel();

for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){

    colsize.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(200);
}
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Do you want to make JTable bigger or change width of Column?

Comment: @smit the column mainly but I believe the column are not re-sizing due to the table size since in the view i can re-size the cloumn but making one column bigger result with the next column to be small to fit within the same table boundary. So I need to make the JTable bigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To size up the  [table#setPreferredSize().](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)

```
table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
```

To size up the columns [table#getColumn().](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumn%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
table.getColumn(columnNames[0]).setPreferredWidth(100);
table.getColumn(columnNames[1]).setPreferredWidth(400);
```

I hope this will help to resolve your issue. If you got any issue while implementing this  then just ask.

Comment: thanks this help. Is there a way to setPerferredWidth() based on the lenght of the value at that column

Comment: You have to put int value to specify width. So you can calculate that width part and you can set that calculated value.

Answer (score 3):

Using `setPreferredSize()` is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). Because `JTable` implements `Scrollable`, overriding `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to return a multiple of `getRowHeight()` may be a better approach.