# How to size a JTable in a JScrollPane without setPreferredSize()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have to get smaller a JTable inside a JScrollPanel. I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913642/re-size-jtable-when-useing-default-table-model) which in the first answer is shown how to do that -but- if I overload the table in order to exceed the panel height it never shows the side scroll bar. Also the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) is mentioned in the topic. Are clear cons of using preferred size but I still haven't figured out what I should do for re-size my Table.

Please, could someone give me a clear explanation?

Thank you,

Andrea

Comment: is about conflict with setXxxSize and in LayoutManager APIs implemented getXxxSize

Comment: but- if I overload the table in order to exceed the panel height it never shows the side scroll bar. == for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting setPreferredSize() for the Scroll Pane and add Jtable to the Scroll Pane.  Just give a try.

Comment: Thank you Naren for your suggestion. I've just figured out how to deal with it. I simply had to modify parameters on setBounds() one level above. I couldn't imagine that would have been as easy as is.